# Multi-Entity Aggregates Axon

Tags: spring-boot, axon

In [Axon Framework](https://axoniq.io/) if I have entities within aggregate who is responsible to save the entity into DB? Say I have root aggregate name library and library aggregate root  hold  book entities.
each book is an entity that need to be persistenced. Who persiste the book entity using Axon? Is it the programmer responsibility or the framework itself?

for example I want to add new book to the library so I have addNewBook command to be intercept by library aggregate but how do I save the new book entity and to where

Answer (score 0):

What's missing from your description is whether you've chosen to use Event Sourcing or State-Stored Aggregates.

Axon Framework is biased on Event Sourcing, so by default expects your Aggregates to be recreated every time based on the event that instance has published. This is why the [base page on Aggregate in the Reference Guide](https://docs.axoniq.io/reference-guide/axon-framework/axon-framework-commands/modeling/aggregate) shows the usages of Event Sourcing Handlers.

Furthermore, if you are doing Event Sourcing, you don't have to worry at all about the persistence of your Aggregate or Aggregate Members within it. As long as you have an Event Store, the events will be maintained. And with those events, Axon can recreate the Aggregate (and its Aggregate Members) at any time.

If you, however, decide against Event Sourcing, the only option you've left is to use a [State-Stored Aggregate](https://docs.axoniq.io/reference-guide/axon-framework/axon-framework-commands/modeling/state-stored-aggregates). If that's what you have chosen for your application, then all you have to do is to make sure that:

1. The Aggregate is an `@Entity` annotated class.
2. That your Aggregate Members are part of this `@Entity` annotated class per regular entity construction.

So, you don't have to worry about retrieving or storing the Aggregate. Axon will take care of that.

Comment: Thank you. I do want to use event sourcing this is the reason I don't understand where aggregates' entity state ae store. Are the also event sourced?

Comment: Ah alright, good to know that's what you're looking for. The answer is short though: yes Axon event sources the entire aggregate state. Thus, also including `@AggregateMember` annotated fields. Granted, that those fields are all set within `@EventSourcingHandler` annotated methods. Only those methods are invoked when an aggregate is sourced from its events.

Comment: I see. Thank you very much. Great framework!!